# Python 2.7: Dedup list by adding suffix

Tags: python, list, deduplication

I'm not sure I'm thinking about this problem correctly. I'd like to write a function which takes a list with duplicates and appends an iterating suffix to "dedup" the list.

For example:

```
dup_list = ['apple','banana','cherry','banana','cherry','orange','cherry']
```

Aiming to return:

```
deduped = ['apple','banana1','cherry1','banana2','cherry2','orange','cherry3']
```

My instinct was to use the pop function while iterating over the list with a while statement, like so:

```
def dedup_suffix(an_list):
dedup=[]
for each in an_list:
    an_list.pop(an_list.index(each)) #pop it out
    i=1 #iterator  
    while each in an_list:
        an_list.pop(an_list.index(each))
        i+=1
        appendage=str(each)+"_"+str(i)
    else:
        appendage=str(each)
    dedup.append(appendage)
return dedup
```

But:

```
>>> dedup_suffix(dup_list)
```

> > > ['apple', 'cherry', 'orange']

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You can't remove items from a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) to keep track of the number of occurrences. I'm assuming your example is correct with respect to `apple`, so that you don't want to add a zero to the first occurrence. For that you need a bit of logic:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()

dup_list = ['apple','banana','cherry','banana','cherry','orange','cherry']
deduped = []
for name in dup_list:
    new = name + str(counter[name]) if counter[name] else name
    counter.update({name: 1})
    deduped.append(new)
```

Comment: Perhaps `str(len(d[name]))` should be `str(counter[name])`?

Comment: It should. My first attempt was collecting everything in a defaultdict, and I fixed almost all locations ;)

Comment: This does not work as intended, as duplicates should always have a suffix conform question example output.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of duplicates using a collections.Counter object. Then make a new list by iterating through that

```
dup_list = ['apple','banana','cherry','banana','cherry','orange','cherry']
c = Counter(dup_list)

dedup=[]
for w in c:
    n = c[w]
    if n == 1:
        dedup.append(w)
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            dedup.append(w+str(i))
```